# How can I fix a file name in a System Error message not displaying properly?

Tags: filenames, dll

I'm getting an error message when I try to launch a program saying I don't have a specific .dll file, but the name of the file itself is displayed as gibberish. It's not the first time something like this happens, where error messages (or other types of popups) aren't displayed properly.

I've tried changing the language (it was originally in Japanese) and while the rest of the message changed, the file name is still unreadable.

Is there a way I can fix this? I'm not so concerned about this particular program not working, I just want to fix the characters not displaying properly.

[image: The message in question]

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to reinstall the program, like shown in your error message?
If not, please do it and **(if existing and needed)** make sure you install all frameworks, visual c++ redistributables inside the installation folder of your software.

You say its originally in japanese, did you tried to install the japanese language package in Windows?

You can find various language packages in the Microsoft Store on Windows 10, they are called "Local Experience Packs".

[Local Experience Packs - Microsoft Store (W10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CeVB.png)

You can also try to add the language in the Windows 10 Settings.
Go to: Windows Settings --> Time & Language --> Language

[Windows Settings - Language (W10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFueT.png)